# Detect click on vertex or edge of polygon in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

Is it possible to distinguish between clicks on edges, vertices and the interior of a polygon in OpenLayers 3?  I'm happy to move to OpenLayers 4 if that makes it easier.

Or am I better off drawing the polygon as a series of lines with small marker polygons at each vertex and then detect clicks on each of these?

Answer (score 1):

Check this class [ol.interaction.Snap](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.interaction.Snap.html), it's provide some options to snap on vertex and/or edge of a feature. If you use it with the change event you can distinguish if is it clicked on vertex or edge. If is not, check if the click is inside the polygon or outside ([intersectsCoordinate](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.geom.Polygon.html#intersectsCoordinate)).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this feature does not exist in OL. All you can get is the layer or the feature at a specific location, but not *what part* of the feature.

It is likely a lot of work to implement such a feature. If you try it, you might want to use some additional library like [JSTS](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts) in combination with the [getClosestPoint](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.geom.Geometry.html#getClosestPoint) of the Geometry.

However, I think the solution you suggested yourself is the simplest one split the object into multiple features and select the best matching one (e.g. edge > vertex > interior) with [forEachFeatureAtPixel](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.CanvasMap.html#forEachFeatureAtPixel).